# Create matrix from simple pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a simple dataframe with two columns and would like to transform it into a matrix with same number of columns and rows.

I have several combinations as rows and would like to copy those into columns in order to have a view of the strength of the relationships on a visual level (possibly a chord diagram).

This is a sample the dataframe I'm using:

```
variables         count
a                  13
b                   9
c                   8
d                   6
e                  10
f                  12
g                   9
h                   7
a_b                 7
a_b_h               8
```

And this is the output I would like to have, taking into account that I have several combinations, not just pair wise.

```
         a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  a_b a_b_h
a       13  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0
b        7  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0
c        0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0    0
d        0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0    0
e        0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0    0
f        0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0    0
g        0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0    0
h        0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0    0
a_b      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7    0
a_b_h    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    8
```

And so on, with all the combinations.

The aim is to then build a chord diagram like the one below - which shows the strength of the relationships between variables

Comment: but how a_b_h have to be handled as it is in source and then in cross-table interection a - h gives 0

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.diag`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"variables": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "a_b", "a_b_h"],
                   "count": [13, 9, 8, 6, 10, 12, 9, 7, 7, 8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df["count"]), columns=df["variables"], index=df["variables"])
```

Output:

```
variables   a  b  c  d   e   f  g  h  a_b  a_b_h
variables                                       
a          13  0  0  0   0   0  0  0    0      0
b           0  9  0  0   0   0  0  0    0      0
c           0  0  8  0   0   0  0  0    0      0
d           0  0  0  6   0   0  0  0    0      0
e           0  0  0  0  10   0  0  0    0      0
f           0  0  0  0   0  12  0  0    0      0
g           0  0  0  0   0   0  9  0    0      0
h           0  0  0  0   0   0  0  7    0      0
a_b         0  0  0  0   0   0  0  0    7      0
a_b_h       0  0  0  0   0   0  0  0    0      8
```